# '???' Showing up in string on iOS Device, but not Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, string, utf-8, ios-simulator

I have found that the same cell with the same text and the same font is changing ’ characters into ??? on a device, but the simulator displays the character fine. This is also happening with some other special characters.

Here are some screenshots to help explain what I mean:

On the iOS Simulator
[image]

On my iPhone 6 Plus (or any iOS device)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Code and Logs**

JSON response from server (in Simulator)

> {"title":"The science behind Netflix’s first major redesign in four years"}`

JSON response from server (on Device)

> {"title":"The science behind Netflix???s first major redesign in four years"}`

CODE (I am using Xamarin so it is in C#)

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(response);
cell.TextLabel.Title = obj["title"].ToString();
```

Obviously the response from the server is different for the simulator and the device. How could this be though? They are both going to the same place, getting the same info...

Thanks again!

**Some more details**

The data is being downloaded using C#'s System.Net.WebClient's DownloadString() method.

The data is served up by our own servers (running node.js and expressjs)

The node endpoint gets the data from our database, encodes it to JSON and then uses `res.send` to display it.

Hope this helps some more! Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Show log output for the relevant values.

Comment: Updated my question above.

Comment: Well it sounds like a bug in Xamarin's ToString(), doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps.... It doesn't explain why the same could would work in the simulator but not work on the device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are downloading JSON data.  JSON is typically (but not required to be) encoded in UTF-8.

The JSON data in question contains Unicode codepoint `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, rather than `U+0027 APOSTROPHE`. Codepoint `U+2019` is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `0xE2 0x80 0x99`.

When downloading the JSON, the raw bytes are not being interpreted as UTF-8 when converted to a `String`.  The bytes are being interpreted in a charset that does not support bytes `0xE2`, `0x80`, or `0x99`, so they are each being converted to either codepoint `U+003F QUESTION MARK` or `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` (depending on how the decoder is implemented).

According to Xamarin's [`WebClient.DownloadString()`](http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aSystem.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(System.String)) documentation (which matches [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx)):

> This method retrieves the specified resource. After it downloads the resource, **the method uses the encoding specified in the `WebClient.Encoding` property** to convert the resource to a `String`.

And according to Xamarin's [`WebClient.Encoding`](http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aSystem.Net.WebClient.Encoding) documentation (which is similar to [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx)):

> When a string is downloaded using the `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString` or `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` methods, `System.Net.WebClient` uses the `System.Text.Encoding` returned by this to convert the downloaded byte array into a string.

Xamarin's documentation does not state what the default value of the `WebClient.Encoding` property is, but the MSDN documentation does:

> The default value of this property is the encoding returned by `Default`.

Where `Default` is referring to the [`System.Text.Encoding.Default`](http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aSystem.Text.Encoding.Default) property:

> Gets an encoding for the operating system's **current ANSI code page**.
>
> **Note:**
>   **Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can even change on a single computer. Therefore, data streamed from one computer to another or even retrieved at different times on the same computer might be translated incorrectly.** In addition, the encoding returned by the Default property uses best-fit fallback to map unsupported characters to characters supported by the code page. For these two reasons, using the default encoding is generally not recommended. To ensure that encoded bytes are decoded properly, you should use a Unicode encoding, such as UTF8Encoding or UnicodeEncoding, with a preamble. Another option is to use a higher-level protocol to ensure that the same format is used for encoding and decoding.

So, the charset used by `System.Text.Encoding.Default` in the iOS Simulator (which is the underlying OS's charset) is different than the charset used by `System.Text.Encoding.Default` in the iOS device.  That would account for the difference in decoding that you are seeing.

Assuming that the JSON really is encoded as UTF-8 during transmission, you need to set the `WebClient.Encoding` property to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` before calling `WebClient.DowloadString()`.  Then it will decode correctly on both device and simulator.

Comment: This was in fact the case. The iOS simulator's default was UTF8 but the iPhone's was ASCII. Setting the client's encoding to UTF8 cleared it up. Thanks a lot!